# How to change position of default welcome message in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, default-values, ultimo

I am customizing my Magento theme. I have come across the problem of customizing default Magento message. Is there any way to change to position this in the middle. Right now it is on the left side. I have applied the ultimo theme in which I am using this.

Moreover, in themes setting, there is no option to customize the default header. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

I am using Magento 2.1 community edition.

Comment: share your web URL to check if can be done via CSS

Comment: @ManojDeswal sorry but i did not have a live site i am using this on my local server. For your info i am using the ultimo theme.

Comment: you need to modify some code inside "header-top-container".. welcome message is coming in "left-column".... You need to create extra column and place your welcome message code inside that.... little CSS usage will help to put at right place wherever you want

Comment: also you can define width to "left-column" and then welcome message can  float to right

Comment: @ManojDeswal one thing i have searched and find it to change the css in the theme by custome.less css file. But how i would know the classes name. I cannot see the html or in phtml files where can i view these things. May be ultimo theme is inheriting these things from parent (luma base theme).

Comment: change css: taking "header-top-container" as parent class and defining width to "left-column" like .header-top-container .left-column{width:70%;} and .header-top-container .left-column .item:last-child{float:right;}

Comment: let me check this by adding a custom.css file. Another thing i want to ask is how to add an image is it possible in css or otherwise i have to locate the html files. Like in header i want to add 50% sale small black box

Comment: Need to Locate the header file , let me check if I can download the theme then I ll help you out

Comment: @ManojDeswal it will be great help.

Comment: Whatever possible , I ll help..but you should post your questions..if not me than anyone else can help you out

Comment: i have posted this . If you asked i can edit it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65404/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-tech-geek).

Comment: @ManojDeswal i am including image in header.phtml but this is giving me forbidden 403 error. i am giving img src a relative path. May be i am doing something wrong?

Comment: where you are including image in header ... let me know location in this demo http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/default/

Comment: in top right where the flag is . i have changed the position of default message to there now i want to add the image there.

Comment: i am including like this `<div class="jb_image"><img src="app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/web/images/jbpro1.png;"></div>`

Comment: i am not on system currently... will revert you soon after checking files

Comment: @ManojDeswal sure

Comment: try this way , if works then good otherwise I ll revert after checking :" <img src="{{view url="images/jbpro1.png‌​"}}" alt="jbpro" />"

Comment: and where to upload this image?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/web/images/jbpro1.png‌​

Comment: okay i am doing this

Comment: no this is not working it is giving some error in hash and % signs.

Comment: ok, then  I need to see, once I ll check I ll revert with proper solution

Comment: it will be a great help manoj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65875/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-tech-geek).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow below steps to add image in top right container of your header:

**1)** Your image should at right location to work, **for example taking "test.jpg"**

> ```
> /app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/web/images/test.jpg
> ```

2) Find your `header.phtml` at below location

> ```
> /app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Infortis_Base/templates/html/header.phtml
> ```

and paste this line of code

> ```
> <div class="jb_image"> <img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/test.jpg'); ?>' alt="test"></div>
> ```

inside this section `<div class="right-column"></div>`

Clear and flush cache.

Comment: thank you manoj its working fine. I have done this int he same way.