# Magento 2 how to interchange position of store view and Default welcome msg in luma theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

How to interchange the position of store view and Default welcome msg in luma theme Magento 2.1.7

[image]

Comment: You can check and follow this document
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192694/how-to-change-position-of-default-welcome-message-in-magento-2

Comment: This will help you out'